# Trying to call an Excel document from a Word document

Tags: excel, xml, vba, ms-word, document

I have a tab set up in Word where users can click on the name of a particular document and it will open as a new Word document.  I need to add an excel template to be called up the same way, but I think I need to define it some way so Word will do that.

Here is the routine, and all of the .dot and .dotm templates are called up with no problem.  But Case "btnHR7" has an Excel template and it does not work as I have it:

```
Sub SplitHR_OnAction(ByVal control As IRibbonControl)
    Select Case control.ID
        Case "btnHR1"
            Documents.Add Template:="\\FAPVM\sstu_shared\Templates\SSTUWA Normal\ACCIDENT INCIDENT FORM.dotm", NewTemplate:=False
        Case "btnHR2"
            Documents.Add Template:="\\FAPVM\sstu_shared\Templates\SSTUWA Normal\ACCIDENT INCIDENT FORM.dotm", NewTemplate:=False
        Case "btnHR3"
            Documents.Add Template:="\\FAPVM\sstu_shared\Templates\SSTUWA Normal\AD-HOC TIME TAKEN.dot", NewTemplate:=False
        Case "btnHR4"
            Documents.Add Template:="\\FAPVM\sstu_shared\Templates\SSTUWA Normal\Application for Leave.dot", NewTemplate:=False
        Case "btnHR5"
            Documents.Add Template:="\\FAPVM\sstu_shared\Templates\SSTUWA Normal\Application for RDOs - AD.dot", NewTemplate:=False
        Case "btnHR6"
            Documents.Add Template:="\\FAPVM\sstu_shared\Templates\SSTUWA Normal\Application for RDOs - IN.dot", NewTemplate:=False
        Case "btnHR7"
            Documents.Add Template:=oExcel.Workbooks.Open("\\FAPVM\sstu_shared\Templates\SSTUWA Normal\Time Sheet Casual.xltm"), NewTemplate:=False
        Case "btnHR8"
            Documents.Add Template:="\\FAPVM\sstu_shared\Templates\SSTUWA Normal\ADMIN - ELECT WORKING HRS.dotm", NewTemplate:=False
        Case "btnHR9"
            Documents.Add Template:="\\FAPVM\sstu_shared\Templates\SSTUWA Normal\NEW EMPLOYEE INFORMATION.dotm", NewTemplate:=False
        Case "btnHR10"
            Documents.Add Template:="\\FAPVM\sstu_shared\Templates\SSTUWA Normal\Overtime Application.dot", NewTemplate:=False
        Case "btnHR11"
            Documents.Add Template:="\\FAPVM\sstu_shared\Templates\SSTUWA Normal\PD APPLICATION FORM.doc", NewTemplate:=False
        Case "btnHR12"
             Documents.Add Template:="\\FAPVM\sstu_shared\Templates\SSTUWA Normal\RDO Alteration.dotm", NewTemplate:=False
        Case "btnHR13"
            Documents.Add Template:="\\FAPVM\sstu_shared\Templates\SSTUWA Normal\REQUEST FOR TRAVEL.dot", NewTemplate:=False
        Case "btnHR14"
            Documents.Add Template:="\\FAPVM\sstu_shared\Templates\SSTUWA Normal\TOIL APPLICATION - CL.dot", NewTemplate:=False
        Case "btnHR15"
            Documents.Add Template:="\\FAPVM\sstu_shared\Templates\SSTUWA Normal\TOIL APPLICATION - IN.dot", NewTemplate:=False
        End Select

End Sub
```

I have made sure that under References the Microsoft Excel 14.0 Object Library is ticked.

The actual tab in word uses MyRibbon.xml to show the icons for the different documents, and the routine containing the above is:

```
        <button id="btnHR9" label="NEW EMPLOYEE INFORMATION " imageMso="MasterDocumentShow" onAction="Module1.SplitHR_OnAction" />     
        <button id="btnHR10" label="Overtime Application " imageMso="MasterDocumentShow" onAction="Module1.SplitHR_OnAction" /> 
                    <button id="btnHR11" label="PD APPLICATION FORM " imageMso="MasterDocumentShow" onAction="Module1.SplitHR_OnAction" />
                    <button id="btnHR12" label="RDO Alteration " imageMso="MasterDocumentShow" onAction="Module1.SplitHR_OnAction" /> 
        <button id="btnHR13" label="REQUEST FOR TRAVEL " imageMso="MasterDocumentShow" onAction="Module1.SplitHR_OnAction" />
        <button id="btnHR14" label="TOIL APPLICATION - CLERICALS " imageMso="MasterDocumentShow" onAction="Module1.SplitHR_OnAction" />
                    <button id="btnHR15" label="TOIL APPLICATION - INDUSTRIAL " imageMso="MasterDocumentShow" onAction="Module1.SplitHR_OnAction" />  
    </menu> 
</splitButton>
```

How can I call the excel template from the routines?  Do I need to add a subroutine somewhere defining the Excel document?

Comment: Try `ActiveDocument.FollowHyperlink pathToTheFileHere`

Comment: Did you mean something like this? Case "btnHR7"
            ActiveDocument.FollowHyperlink pathToTheFileHere:="\\FAPVM\sstu_shared\Templates\SSTUWA Normal\Time Sheet Casual.xltm", NewTemplate:=False   When I tried that I got a "Compile error in hidden module: Module1"

Comment: `ActiveDocument.FollowHyperlink "\\FAPVM\sstu_shared\Templates\SSTUWA Normal\Time Sheet Casual.xltm"`

Comment: Still get the Compile error in hidden module: Module 1.

Comment: Is that coming from your Excel template, or from Word?

Comment: I resolved it by creating a subroutine:    Sub OpenExcelWorkbook()

Dim objXLApplication As Excel.Application
Dim objXLWorkbook As Excel.Workbook

Set objXLApplication = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

Set objXLWorkbook = objXLApplication.Workbooks.Open("\\FAPVM\sstu_shared\Templates\SSTUWA Normal\Time Sheet Casual.xltm")

objXLApplication.Visible = True

'........
'........


End Sub  and then set it to call that subroutine when the particular icon is clicked.

Comment: OK  -good to hear you got it working.